# Getting an object class' type and property and values

Tags: c#, .net

A little obscure, and certainly strongly typed-ness would help here but I can't afford that luxury in the short amount of time I have to fix this problem.

say I have this method:

```
public static void MyMethod(string words, object params)
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.Execute(words, params);
}
```

I'm looking for a way to, during runtime, log the `params` properties and values that are being passed in. I can get the properties but unable to find a way to extract the values. I assume reflection is used but I only would know how to do this if the object was strongly typed.

Comment: Can we have an example? "object params" sounds weird to me...

Comment: Use `Unity.Interception` to create an interceptor. You can set the interceptor to watch this method, and will be able to pick out the parameters at will. One note though: you will need to ditch the `static` keyword. Not a lot of static methods can be intercepted or mocked or facaded.

Comment: Since you're logging it, why not either `.ToString()` all the values or just convert them all to JSON?

Comment: You could JSON serialize `params`  using JSON.net (or some other serialize) and log that.

Comment: [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo - it's sometimes a class, it's sometimes an anonymous object. Using Dapper.

Comment: @kmc059000 - bingo. this ought to work for my purposes. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using reflection (`Logger` class is based on your own implementation and is being used just for the example purpose):

```
public static void MyMethod(String words, Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(objType.GetProperties());

    Logger.Log(
        "Object of type '{0}' with properties:",
        objType.ToString()
    );

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        Logger.Log("  - {0} [Type = {1}] [Value = {2}]",
            prop.Name,
            prop.PropertyType,
            prop.GetValue(this, null)
        );
    }

    connection.Open();
    connection.Execute(words, obj);
}
```

Main documentation references:

- [Type.GetProperties()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [PropertyInfo.GetValue(Object, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach before - an extension method on Object to convert to an Expando dynamic object:

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object value)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType()))
    expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(value));

    return expando as ExpandoObject;
}
```

Then you can use the IDictionary interface to interact with the object and know exactly the key/value pairs.